# Not able to get nested objects from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, rest

I have tried to get some help on this matter previously, but nothing seems to work. I want to retrieve some nested objects from a REST API.

This is the code that I am using and that should work:

```
  var url = 'XXXXX';

$(function(){

            $.getJSON(url, function(data){

              $.each(data.paths,function(i,emp){          
                var b = this.places[0].place_radius;

                console.log(b);
                });



            });

});
```

However, I get this error message when I try to execute it in a web browser:

```
25
25
apirest.html:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'place_radius' of undefined
```

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: It seems that the third entry in `data.paths` does not include any "places" (i.e. `places: Array[0]`).

Comment: What does `data` actually look like?  And do you mean `place_radius` or `place_position`?

Comment: (to Teepeemm) Hi, with data I would refer to the whole JSON. I meant place_radius, but it doesn't really matter as it cannot access any nested objects.

(to showdev) But, how come I get the results, and then the application crashes?

Comment: Seems like the results are
25, 25, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined. What should I even do in this situation...?

Comment: You're assuming that all elements in paths have a places array that contains a zeroth element, which has a place_radius property.  That isn't the case, look at the data you're receiving.  You will have to check if those structures exist before trying to access their children.

Comment: You get results from the first two entries ("25"). But no "places" exist for the third iteration, so you get an "undefined" error. I suggest that you test for `places.length` before trying to access an iteration's "place" data. That being said, it might be helpful to provide more detail about what you're doing with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to quickly check a bunch of child elements, and assign the correct value to "b", or false if something didn't exist.  Note that if place_radius is falsy (evaluates to bool false, so zero for example) you'll have to use a more careful technique.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data){
  $.each(data.paths,function(i,emp){
    var b = this.places && this.places[0] && this.places[0].place_radius || false;
    if (b === false) {
      console.log("that thing did not exist");
    } else {
      console.log(b);
    }
  });
});
```